Expressing a chain of boolean ORs for variable to be squeeze within an interval?
I am a network engineer facing a modeling challenge related to the delay constraints of a network transmission problem. My objective is to capture the behavior of transmission delays under different operating conditions $g_1,g_2,g_3,...g_i$ using a constrained optimization model.
The specific constraints I am working with is expressed as follows:
$\begin{array}{l}
{x_1} = 1 \Rightarrow \left( {1 - 1} \right){d_{\min }} + {g_1} \le d_1 \le 1{d_{\max }}\\
{\rm{OR}}\\
{x_2} = 1 \Rightarrow \left( {2 - 1} \right){d_{\min }} + {g_2} \le d_2 \le 2{d_{\max }}\\
{\rm{OR}}\\
{x_3} = 1 \Rightarrow \left( {3 - 1} \right){d_{\min }} + {g_3} \le d_3 \le 3{d_{\max }}\\
{\rm{OR}}\\
......................................................\\
{x_i} = 1 \Rightarrow \left( {i - 1} \right){d_{\min }} + {g_i} \le d_i \le i{d_{\max }}
\end{array}$

$g_i$ represents a convex function of another variable linked to the operation of our system. Currently, we are still trying to construct a good $g_i$. And note that these $g_i$ change a lot from big to small or vice versa during the operation.
$d_i$ is a continuous decision variable with bound $d_\min$ and $d_\max$
$x_i$ is a binary decision variable indicating the choice of transmission mode.
$i$ is an index parameter that runs through the possible modes.
The final transmission delay is ${d_{{\rm{final}}}} = \min \left\{ {d_1,d_2,d_3,\dots,d_i} \right\}$

My question is about formulating these constraints.
Specifically, How can I express a chain of boolean ORs for the variable $d_i$ to be constrained within intervals as shown above? This formulation is critical for accurately modeling the delay based on the chosen transmission mode $x_i$.
Currently, I am having a global solver BARON/SCIP. I have check the seemingly related post here and here but I cannot find anyway to applied them to my problem.
P/S: I know that there must be some kind of Big M formulation. If I know about $d_\min$ and $d_\max$, does this knowledge help me choose Big-M ?

If $d_i \le d_{max}$, then $d_i \le i \cdot d_{max}$ is redundant (and thus useless).

Well that is only happens when $x_1 = 1$. If $x_2 = 1$ then $d_1 \le 2d_{max}$.

You asked for $$\bigvee_i \left(x_i = 1 \implies \left( (i - 1) d_\min + {g_i} \le d_i \le i d_\max\right)\right)$$ but do you maybe want $$\bigvee_i \left( (i - 1) d_\min + g_i \le d_i \le i d_\max\right)$$ instead?

Well thank you so much ! In some case that will even work better ! Would you kindly turn it into an official answer !

It would just be part 1 of the answer by @Kuifje, together with $\sum_i x_i \ge 1$.

@RobPratt You means $\bigvee_i \left( (i - 1) d_\min + g_i \le d_i \le i d_\max\right)$ become this ?
$\left{ \begin{array}{l}
{L_i} - {M_i}(1 - {x_i}) \le {d_i} \le {U_i} + {M_i}(1 - {x_i})\
\sum\limits_i {{x_i}}  \ge 1
\end{array} \right.$

Yes, that’s what I mean.

I suspect your problem is not well modeled. But if it is you could proceed in two steps:

Enforce the implication $x_i=1 \implies L_i \le d_i \le U_i$ as follows:
$$
L_i - M_i(1-x_i) \le d_i \le U_i + M_i (1-x_i)
$$
where $L_i = (i-1)d_{min} +g_i$, $U_i=id_{max}$ and $M_i$ a big-M constant.
Enforce $\bigvee_i\left(L_i - M_i(1-x_i) \le d_i \le U_i + M_i (1-x_i)\right)$ with:
\begin{align}
L_i - M_i(2-x_i-y_i) &\le d_i \le U_i + M_i (2-x_i-y_i) \\
\sum_i y_i &\ge 1
\end{align}


Thank you but when $\sum\limits_i {{y_i}}  = 1$ does that mean we have exclusive or ? Also I do not understand why the boolean chain OR can be enforce by
$\bigvee_i\left(L_i - M_i(1-x_i) \le d_i \le U_i + M_i (1-x_i)\right)$
